# Where to put utility scripts in Debian but not in the PATH?

Tags: debian, path

I have a web application with a database back-end. I have some utility scripts that are used to initialize the database. I want to include these scripts in the Debian package, but they are dangerous as they drop the schema and recreate.

So, I do not want to put these scripts in a directory in the PATH. Where do scripts of this nature go on a Debian system? (Note that these scripts are *not* package maintainer scripts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian's got a pretty comprehensive [policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html) so it's usually worth referring to that.  I think this covers it,

> 9.1.1 File System Structure
>
> The location of all files and directories must comply with the
>   Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS), version 2.3, with the exceptions
>   noted below, and except where doing so would violate other terms of
>   Debian Policy.

And checking over the [FHS](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/fhs/fhs-2.3.html#USRLIBLIBRARIESFORPROGRAMMINGANDPA) we find,

> /usr/lib : Libraries for programming and packages
>
> Purpose
>
> /usr/lib includes object files, libraries, and internal binaries that
>   are not intended to be executed directly by users or shell scripts.
>   [22]
>
> Applications may use a single subdirectory under /usr/lib. If an
>   application uses a subdirectory, all architecture-dependent data
>   exclusively used by the application must be placed within that
>   subdirectory.

then back to the Debian policy,

> The requirement for object files, internal binaries, and libraries,
>   including libc.so.*, to be located directly under /lib{,32}
>   and /usr/lib{,32} is amended, permitting files to instead be installed
>   to /lib/triplet and /usr/lib/triplet, where triplet is the value
>   returned by dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH for the
>   architecture of the package. Packages may not install files to any
>   triplet path other than the one matching the architecture of that
>   package; for instance, an Architecture: amd64 package containing
>   32-bit x86 libraries may not install these libraries to
>   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu. [69]
>
> Applications may also use a single subdirectory under /usr/lib/triplet.
>
> The execution time linker/loader, ld*, must still be made available in the existing
>   location under /lib or /lib64 since this is
>   part of the ELF ABI for the architecture.

Answer (score 2):

A common place for executables internal to a program is `/usr/lib/program/`.

(Older Debian systems use `/usr/libexec/`, but this isn't FHS-compliant.)

You could also modify the scripts to, for example, warn the user and exit if `--force` is not given in command line.

Answer (score 1):

Where's your install root? If in /usr/local, I'd personally put them in /usr/local/sbin or /usr/local/etc/scripts directory. Normal users shouldn't have sbin in their PATH, and definitely not anything in etc. If it's in /opt, then you're even safer, since people will need to explicitly add /opt/WHATEVER/bin to their PATH, and you can put them anywhere but bin.

Do your scripts even need to have execute bit set? If you force people to run
`bash my_schema_loader.sh`
instead of running
`my_schema_loader.sh`
it will prevent most unintentional uses, but not interfere much with intentional use.

Comment: Many normal users have sbin in $PATH because unfortunately that's where such utilities as `ping` or `ip` are.